# ReactJS+Redux: How to handle a prop that depends on another props

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, web-component, redux-router

I am creating a `Graph` a `React.Component`. When `componentWillMount`, this graph will be in charge of loading a configuration file using an Async Actions. Configuration file also contains a query information that needs to be fetched.

For now, I am chaining the two requests (configuration + query) and store their results in the current Redux state.

```
{
    configurations: [{
        "my-configuration": 
        {
            // information about the configuration
            query: "my-query"
        }
    }],
    queries: [{
        "my-query" : {
            // information about the query
        }
    }]
}
```

I'd like my `Graph` component to be `connected` to both variables. However, I am not aware of the query name before the configuration is fetched.

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => ({
    configuration: state.getIn([
        "configurations",
        ownProps.configurationName
    ]),
    query: state.getIn([
        "queries",
        queryName // the name of the query comes is known in the configuration
    ]),
});
```

I might face a design issue, but I wanted to have your feedback. How would you deal this situation ?

For now, I created a state for the component but it would need to be in sync with the redux state.

**Environment**

- react@15.3.1
- redux@3.6.0
- redux-thunk@2.1.0

Comment: What stops you to receive `queryName` from configuration and use it to get query in props?

Comment: @elmeister, how would you do that ?

Answer (score 1):

#### Edit: what if myConfig is null and waiting to be fetched from server?

Selector becomes

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  const myConfig = state.getIn([
    "configurations",
    ownProps.configurationName
  ]);
  return {
    configuration: myConfig,
    query: myConfig ? state.getIn([
        "queries",
        myConfig.queryName 
    ]) : *defaultQuery*,
  };
};
```

And you should handle getting `myConfig` in async action.

```
const getMyConfig = (...args) => (dispatch) => {
  dispatch(GET_MY_CONFIG_REQUEST);
  api.getMyConfig(...args)
    .then((res) => dispatch({ type: GET_MY_CONFIG_SUCCESS, res }))
    .catch((err) => dispatch({ type: GET_MY_CONFIG_FAIL, err }));
}
```

And in reducer need to update `myConfig` upon GET_MY_CONFIG_SUCCESS action

```
...
case GET_MY_CONFIG_SUCCESS:
  return { ...state, myConfig: action.res };
...
```

#### Original Answer

something like this?

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  const myConfig = state.getIn([
    "configurations",
    ownProps.configurationName
  ]);
  return {
    configuration: myConfig,
    query: state.getIn([
        "queries",
        myConfig.queryName 
    ]),
  };
};
```

Comment: Something like this, but myConfig can be null as it as not yet been fetched from the server.

Answer (score 0):

Reading this nice article about things you [should know about Redux](https://medium.com/horrible-hacks/things-i-wish-i-knew-about-redux-9924abf2f9e0#.otqk6oiji), here is what you will find:

> Denormalizing data in mapStateToProps is normal. When I first started using Redux, I wasn’t sure if it was kosher to do “computation” in mapStateToProps functions. I didn’t see examples of this in the Redux repo or docs. It took a few weeks for me to find somebody else using a “selector” in mapStateToProps. You have no idea how excited I was to discover somebody else doing this!

Hope this could help someone else!